# Reordering of table rows with arrow images for up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I want to add small images-arrows for moving up and down on table row in Javascript (maybe jQuery) and save the reordered table (only the order) in cookie for further use. An example would be - Joomla, inside the admin area in the Articles area (but that is done with php). Thanks.

Comment: You want to reverse the order of all the items, or at a cell-by-level?

Comment: I want to reorder the rows, whatever they contain, that would be swapping two rows with everything inside (images, other tables etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably can be refactored a bit more, but I leave the saving to you:

```
function swap(a, b, direction){
  var html = a.wrapInner('<tr></tr>').html()
  a.replaceWith(b.wrapInner('<tr></tr>').html())
  b.replaceWith(html)
}
function getParent(cell){ return $(cell).parent('tr') }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.upArrow').live('click', function(){
    var parent = getParent(this)
    var prev = parent.prev('tr')
    if(prev.length == 1){ swap(prev, parent); }
  })
  $('.downArrow').live('click', function(){
    var parent = getParent(this)
    var next = parent.next('tr')
    if(next.length == 1){ swap(next, parent) }
  })
})
```

Assuming this table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td class="upArrow">up</td><td class="downArrow">down</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td class="upArrow">up</td><td class="downArrow">down</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td class="upArrow">up</td><td class="downArrow">down</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: jquery 1.3 released the closest method which could be used in your getParent method.

Comment: you also might want to change your swap to next.after(parent.clone());parent.remove();  and prev.before....

Comment: Look into jquery's `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` for a better way to achieve the `swap` method that preserves events and data.

Answer (score 2):

For the jQuery part of things, you could look into modifying [this plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) to use clicking on icons instead of drag-and-drop.

Comment: Per the comments, you need to change lines 92-94 to use `.on` vs `.bind` for jQuery 1.10+

Answer (score 2):

```
function UpperBttn_Pressed(this) {

    var RowIndex = X.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var ParentTable = X.parentNode.parentNode.parentElement;
    if (RowIndex != 0 && RowIndex != 1) {
        ParentTable.moveRow(RowIndex, RowIndex - 1);
    }

}
function DownBttn_Pressed(this) {

    var RowIndex = X.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var ParentTable = X.parentNode.parentNode.parentElement;
    var NthRow = GetElement("dataTable").rows.length;
    if (RowIndex!=NthRow-1) {
        ParentTable.moveRow(RowIndex, RowIndex + 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I found it and one of the posts set me on the right course, so for anyone else that googles here

using jQuery

```
function Func(trigger, blnUp){
var trigRow = $("#" + trigger.id).parent().parent();
var prevRow = trigrRow.prev();
var nextRow = trigRow.next();
var trigRowHTML = "";
if(blnUp){
    trigRowHTML = prevRow.html();
    prevRow.html(trig.html());
}else{
    trigRowHTML = nextRow.html();
    nextRow.html(trig.html());
    }
}
```

the table would need to look something like

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><a onclick="Func(this, true)">UP</a></td><td><a onclick="Func(this, false)">UP</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><a onclick="Func(this, true)">UP</a></td><td><a onclick="Func(this, false)">UP</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td><a onclick="Func(this, true)">UP</a></td><td><a onclick="Func(this, false)">UP</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have a table like the other answer, you should be able to just remove one of the .parent() calls and it will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

insertBefore() and insertAfter() work nicely. In the example below I have a couple of A tags in a table. Clicking one moves the row down, the other up. If you give your rows that are allowed to move (maybe you don't want to move rows above header rows or below footer rows) class of _movable, then they will only move between header and footer rows.

Here's one of the A tags: <a onclick="return moveUp(this);" href="javascript:return 0;">up</a>

```
function moveUp(aEl) {
    var me = $($(aEl).parents('tr').get(0));
    var prev = me.prev('tr');
    if (prev.attr('class') == '_movable') me.insertBefore(prev);
    return false;
}
function moveDown(aEl) {
    var me = $($(aEl).parents('tr').get(0));
    var next = me.next('tr');
    if (next.attr('class') == '_movable') me.insertAfter(next);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with some simple jQuery selectors, capture the click event on the arrows, and use selectors to get the next / previous element and swap them.

Then use selector to get id of each row, however you are storing that - could have each row identified setting id on the tr to make selection easy. Sample selectors are [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and store it to a cookie, again simple JS for that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.upArrow').livequery('click', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var prev = row.prev();
        if (prev.length == 1) {
                row.detach();
                prev.before(row);
        }
    });
    $('.downArrow').livequery('click', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var next = row.next('tr');
        if (next.length == 1) {
            row.detach();
            next.after(row);
        }
    });
```